# Merge dictionary items if their keys have a substring equal to the full string of another key in common

Tags: python, dictionary, string-matching

I currently have a dictionary of dictionaries in which some of the items are related. The items which are related to one another invariably follow a pattern illustrated here:

```
{ "item" : { "foo" : "bar", "fizz" : "buzz"},
  "itemSuper" : { "boo" : "far", "bizz" : "fuzz"},
  "itemDuper" : { "omg" : "wtf", "rofl" : "lmao"}}
```

As you can see, the keys of all the dictionaries which are related have a substring in common which is equal to the full key of one of the dictionaries. I would like to go through my dictionary-of-dictionaries combining all of the contents of such related groups into single dictionaries whose keys are the substring by which the matching was done. So, the end-goal is to end up with something like this for all of these groups:

```
{ "item" : { "foo" : "bar", "fizz" : "buzz", "boo" : "far", "bizz" : "fuzz", "omg" : "wtf", "rofl" : "lmao"}}
```

The substring is always the leading part of the key, but may be arbitrary from group to group. So in addition to the `"item", "itemSuper" and "itemDuper"` above, there are `"thingy"`, `"thingySuper"`, and `"thingyDuper"`, along with others of that sort.

There are three possible suffixes for the substring; let's call them `Super`, `Duper` and `Uber`. Any of the groups of items I am interested in can have any or all three of these, but there are no other suffixes that may occur.

Comment: please share what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Is the prefix always same length or always the first word? Or is there any other pattern to know which "parent" key to use?

Comment: Added more detail in the original question in response to h4z3's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it following way:

```
data = { "item" : { "foo" : "bar", "fizz" : "buzz"},
  "itemSuper" : { "boo" : "far", "bizz" : "fuzz"},
  "itemDuper" : { "omg" : "wtf", "rofl" : "lmao"}}
for key1 in list(data.keys()):
    for key2 in list(data.keys()):
        if key1!=key2 and key1 in key2:
            data[key1].update(data[key2])
            del data[key2]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'item': {'foo': 'bar', 'fizz': 'buzz', 'boo': 'far', 'bizz': 'fuzz', 'omg': 'wtf', 'rofl': 'lmao'}}
```

Note that this solution is in-place (it alters `data`) and that I use `for ... in list(...)` - this is crucial, because otherwise I would not be able to `del` inside loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_of_dict = {                                            
  "item" : { "foo" : "bar", "fizz" : "buzz"},      
  "itemSuper" : { "boo" : "far", "bizz" : "fuzz"},
  "itemDuper" : { "omg" : "wtf", "rofl" : "lmao"} 
} 
suffixes = {'Super', 'Duper', 'Uber'}

def get_base(key, suffix_lst):
    for suffix in suffix_lst:
        if key.endswith(suffix):
            return key[:-len(suffix)]
    return key    

res = {}
for k,d in dict_of_dict.items():  
    base = get_base(k, suffixes)
    res.setdefault(base, {}).update(d)      

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'item': {'foo': 'bar', 'fizz': 'buzz', 'boo': 'far', 'bizz': 'fuzz', 'omg': 'wtf', 'rofl': 'lmao'}}
```

Comment: I was writing similar. +1 but I'd be happier if it took a suffix list. It could be defined as a default argument to get_base.

Comment: @KennyOstrom. Good suggestio. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def recombine(k, substring):
    newd = dict()
    newk = dict()

    key = [i for i in k if (substring in i)]  # select out the strings which contains substring
    value = [k[i] for i in key]               # select out the corresponding value of target key
    for i in value: 
        for j in i.items():
            newk[j[0]] = j[1]
    newd[substring] = newk
    return newd

k = { "item" : { "foo" : "bar", "fizz" : "buzz"},
  "itemSuper" : { "boo" : "far", "bizz" : "fuzz"},
  "itemDuper" : { "omg" : "wtf", "rofl" : "lmao"}}
recombine(k, 'item')
```

Output

```
{'item': {'foo': 'bar',
  'fizz': 'buzz',
  'boo': 'far',
  'bizz': 'fuzz',
  'omg': 'wtf',
  'rofl': 'lmao'}}
```